# Sorting a dropdown list changes the option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a web app using HTML, Javascript, JQuery, that constantly fetches new data from the database and display a real-time dashboard. I want to go through a certain column in the data called "Group", get all the unique values, then repopulate a dropdown list with the sorted unique "Group" values. However, before new data is fetched, there would already be an option selected in a dropdown list, say Group 02. I don't want the dashboard to switch to another group. Only when the user selects the new group should the dashboard switch to that group. For discussion sakes let's say there are two groups, "Group 1", "Group 2".

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
let uniqueGroups =[...new Set(d.map(l => `<option>${l.Group}</option>`))];
    let grpCollator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {sensitivity: 'base'});
    uniqueGroups.forEach(element=>{
      if (element.includes('undefined')){
        element = element.replace("undefined", "No Group Assigned");
      }
      if(this.allGroups.includes(element)==false) this.allGroups.push(element)
    })

    //#groupSelection is the id of the dropdown list
    $('#groupSelection').html(this.allGroups.sort(grpCollator.compare));
```

The problem with this code is that it will constantly switch the selected option of my dropdown list to Group 1 (which is the first option after sorting). So even if the user had selected Group 2, this code (which should only sort) will sort AND select the first option Group 1 (which messes up my dashboard as it constantly switches to the group that the user doesn't want to see).

I tried something like this (but it's not working):

```
    // first get the current selected option
    // (Note: I'm not using val, I'm using the actual text that's why you see .text() below)
    let currGrpSelection = $('#groupSelection option:selected').text();
    
    // then I sort
    $('#groupSelection').html(this.allGroups.sort(grpCollator.compare));

    // then I try to set the selected option back to the original one
    $('#groupSelection option:selected').text(currGrpSelection);
```

It doesn't work because this happens with this piece of code:

From a dropdown list of:

```
Group 1
Group 2   <- this is the one user selects
```

It changes to:

```
Group 2   <- the code changes the first option to the one user selected! :(
Group 2
```

Would appreciate any advice. I've been stuck with this issue for a long time...

Comment: Please add your html and css to the question for a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you make this runnable to show that behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example, should be easier than what you did.

```js
// add selected to the option to have it selected.

// cars
const cars = [
  "Volvo",
  "Saab",
  "Opel",
  "Audi"
];

// adding new cars
cars.push("Tesla");

// render new changes
function updateCars(selector) {
  // select the select element;
  const select = document.querySelector(selector);

  // converting the nodeList into an array of car names.
  const currentCars = Array.from(select.children).map(elm => elm.value);


  // loop through cars
  cars.forEach(car => {
    // if the car isn't already there, then add it.
    if (!currentCars.includes(car.toLowerCase())) {

      // creating a new option element;
      const opt = document.createElement("option");

      // setting the car as the text and value;
      opt.text = car;
      opt.value = car;

      // adding the element to the select element;
      select.appendChild(opt);
    }
  })
}

updateCars("#cars")
```

```html
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake.

Trying to use `$("#someId selected:option").text()` as the selected value doesn't work. Once I resort the dropdown list, the selected option automatically becomes the first option.

As such, I changed to use `.val()` instead. Then saving the current value, resorting the list, and re-setting the value of the list to the saved value works.